# HashSet behaviour is surprising

Tags: java, android, hashset

I have searched for this on `stackoverflow` and found unrelated threads for this case. I have also tried on my own, and will keep trying until the solution. But it will be good if someone shows me if i am doing any mistakes in code.

---

I am having a `HashSet` so that i can keep away duplicate strings from being getting added to it. And if `HashSet` is adding then it must be a unique string.

---

My class declarations are :

```
public List<String> ContactsList;
public List<String> ContactsNumbersList;
```

My code to fetch contacts and adding it into these two lists by taking help of `HashSet` so that i keep duplicate numbers away is :

```
    ContactsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ContactsNumbersList = new ArrayList<String>();

    HashSet<String> normalizedNumbersAlreadyFound = new HashSet<>();

    // Contacts Database queries

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER}, null, null,  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.SORT_KEY_PRIMARY +" ASC");


    while (cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

        if (normalizedNumbersAlreadyFound.add(phoneNumber))
        {
            phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace("-","");
            phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(" ","");
            phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace("(","");
            phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(")","");
            ContactsList.add(name);
            ContactsNumbersList.add(phoneNumber);
        }

    }
    cursor.close();
```

---

Well then why my `ContactsNumbersList` having duplicate entries...? Thanking you in advance for any suggestions.. which will help me.

Comment: You replace some chars after making sure that the original String is not present. Might be the cause. Furthermore, why don't you add directly the elements in a Set, and use it afterwards to build a list?

Comment: Probably because you are removing the rubbish from the phone number **after** you add it to the `normalizedNumbersAlreadyFound` set. Try doing the cleanup **before** the check.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with your design.

First and foremost, you don't need `List`s if your goal is to use a collection without duplicates.

Just use your `Set` instead.

Secondly, and specifically to your code, you are checking whether the element is added to your `Set` *before* normalizing it and adding the normalized `String` to the `List`.

Therefore, it may very well be that your `List` will contain duplicates because two elements that differ before normalization may be equal after normalization.

This leads me back to advise you to use your `Set` directly and disregard using a `List` in this use case.

**Example**

```
List<String> source = Arrays.asList("123-456789", "(1)23456789");
System.out.printf("Source List contains: %s%n", source);
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
List<String> unnecessary = new ArrayList<>();
Set<String> useful = new HashSet<>();

for (String s: source) {
    if (set.add(s)) System.out.printf("Added %s to set.%n", s);
    s = s.replaceAll("[()-]", "");
    System.out.printf("\t... now normalized to %s%n", s);
    // s is now normalized
    unnecessary.add(s);
    useful.add(s);
}
System.out.printf(
    "Set contains %s.%nUnnecessary List contains %s.%nUseful Set contains %s.%n", 
    set, 
    unnecessary,
    useful
);
```

**Output**

```
Source List contains: [123-456789, (1)23456789]
Added 123-456789 to set.
    ... now normalized to 123456789
Added (1)23456789 to set.
    ... now normalized to 123456789
Set contains [(1)23456789, 123-456789].
Unnecessary List contains [123456789, 123456789].
Useful Set contains [123456789].
```

Comment: was about to write a similar answer when yours already popped up. +1 for speed and completeness.

Comment: @Mena , Thumbs Up. My Mistake... I missplaced the code... Yes you pointed it so accurately... Upvote is necessary